# All the elements disappear when I click on one of them, but only need the elements that I haven't clicked on to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want all the other elements(that I haven't clicked on) to disappear when I click on one of them, but instead all of them disappear. Here's the Javascript Code:

```js
$(".content-toggler").click(function() {
  let elTriggered = $(this);
  elTriggered.parent().toggleClass("expand");
  $(".content-toggler").each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element) === elTriggered) {
      console.log("Passing on the clicked element...");
    } else {
      $(element).parent().toggleClass("hide");
    }
    console.log($(element))
    console.log(elTriggered)
  });

});
```

```css
.circular-anim {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1em auto;
  /*With 'auto', you center the element according to the margin*/
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.content-toggler {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-style: none;
  background: #8D9CF4;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32.5px;
  left: 188.5px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-content">
  <div class="circular-anim"><button class="content-toggler"></button></div>
  <div class="circular-anim"><button class="content-toggler"></button></div>
  <div class="circular-anim"><button class="content-toggler"></button></div>
  <div class="circular-anim"><button class="content-toggler"></button></div>
</div>
```

By the way, I injected some of the content from the js file and they already work well. Don't be surprised if you see some of the classes missing in the css code.

Why do all my elements disappear even though I want the one that I click on to stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `$()` it creates a new jQuery object, and it will not compare equal to another object even if they refer to the same DOM element.

You can just use the `.not()` function to remove an element from the collection, instead of looping with `.each()` and comparing.

```js
$(".content-toggler").click(function() {
  let elTriggered = $(this);
  elTriggered.parent().toggleClass("expand");
  $(".content-toggler").not(this).toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.circular-anim {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1em auto;
  /*With 'auto', you center the element according to the margin*/
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.content-toggler {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-style: none;
  background: #8D9CF4;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32.5px;
  left: 188.5px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-content">
  <div class="circular-anim"><button class="content-toggler"></button></div>
  <div class="circular-anim"><button class="content-toggler"></button></div>
  <div class="circular-anim"><button class="content-toggler"></button></div>
  <div class="circular-anim"><button class="content-toggler"></button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that saved me the effort of typing the rest of my answer! :)

Comment: It worked, at first it still didn't happen but it was because of a mistype. thanks a lot!